# Capture user Idling using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iis-7, session-timeout

Our site has ifame links to different content sites which are used to do online exams 
Some exams in the content pages are running 3+ hours 
Also exam guard is there for prevent the users doing other stuff while doing the exams

The problem is that once user completed the exams over 3+hrs and come to the parent site (our site)
It has session time out issue in parent page,  (Parent site session time out is set to 180min )

As a solution for this we have implemented following JQuery

```
    var to;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        to = setTimeout("TimeOut()", 10000);
    });

    function TimeOut() {
        $.ajax({ type: "POST",
            url: "KeepAliveDummy.aspx", success: function () {
                to = setTimeout("TimeOut()", 10000);
            }
        });
     };
```

Now the problem is that if one user open Parent site and go away it will keep the session unwantedly,

Any suggestion for capture the idle time?

Answer (score 2):

We can use "mousemove" event and see whether the user is active or not.

I have used the below code to test whether the user idle time reached the Maximum Idle time.

```
  function checkIdleTimeOut() {
        userIdleTime++;
        if( userIdleTime >= maxIdleTime ) {
            alert("Reached max User Idle Time");
            clearInterval(intvl);
        }
        $("#output").html( "userIdleTime: " + userIdleTime );
}
```

I have provided a sample demo, where the max idle time is set to 5 seconds.

Demo at [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zV67j/)